# Getting error "Unable to deserialize the response"

Tags: c#, botframework

I started learning the Microsoft Bot Framework, but when I am trying to use a Connector it always returns:

> "message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "exceptionMessage": "Unable to deserialize the response.",
>     "exceptionType": "Microsoft.Rest.RestException",

Here is the code

```
  public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (message.Type == "Message")
            {
                // calculate something for us to return
                //int length = (message.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

                // return our reply to the user
                //                return message.CreateReplyMessage($"You sent {length} characters");

                //var counter = message.GetBotPerUserInConversationData<int>("counter");

                //// create a reply message   
                //Message replyMessage = message.CreateReplyMessage($"{++counter} You said:{message.Text}");

                //// save our new counter by adding it to the outgoing message
                //replyMessage.SetBotPerUserInConversationData("counter", counter);

                //// return our reply to the user
                ////return replyMessage;

                //                return message.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I got it.", "en");
                // var replyMessage = message.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I heard you.", "en");
                // var connectorr = new ConnectorClient();
                // connectorr.BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:3978/");

                //return await connectorr.Messages.SendMessageAsync(replyMessage);


                var connector = new ConnectorClient();
                connector.BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:3978/api/messages");

               await connector.Messages.SendMessageAsync(message.CreateReplyMessage($"You said:{message.Text}"));
              await  connector.Messages.SendMessageAsync(message.CreateReplyMessage("Yo 2.", "en"));
              await  connector.Messages.SendMessageAsync(message.CreateReplyMessage("Yo 3.", "en"));

                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return HandleSystemMessage(message);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade it to latest version which is 3.8.0.
Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-upgrade-to-v3

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you create a connector inside the bot itset. I am not sure why you want to do that as this seems to create a circular solution. You can use the ConnectorCLient to create your own messageclient that connects to your bot. Is this what you want to achieve?

If you just want to reply a message based on the message you need to use:

return message.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I got it.", "en");

You can connect to you bot by using the emulator or connect it to Skype, FB messanger to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate according to V3.0 specification and see if it works now. I faced some similar issues when code was targeting v1.0 and bot was registered to v3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `await connector.Messages.SendMessageAsync(message.CreateReplyMessage($"You said:{message.Text}"));` use `await context.PostAsync($"You said: {activity.Text}");` and see if that works.